# Comparing two files in haskell / passing two IO Strings to one function

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm new to Haskell and monads and I'm trying to write a simple program that loads two files into Strings and then compares the String as Char-lists using a comparison-function (which later on should be replaced by something fancy). But I couldn't figure out how to pass these IO lists to the comparison function and to the final print output... In the code

```
import System.IO  
import Control.Monad


cmp :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
cmp []      []      = True
cmp []      (y:ys)  = False
cmp (x:xs)  []      = False
cmp (x:xs)  (y:ys)  = (x==y) && cmp xs ys

main = do
    l1 <- readFile "dat1"
    l2 <- readFile "dat2"
    print . cmp =<< l1 =<<l2
```

the last line

```
print . cmp =<< l1 =<<l2
```

does not work and has to be replaced... But how to do that?

Thanks a lot for any suggestions in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`l1` and `l2` are already `String`, so you can use `print $ cmp l1 l2` directly.

Answer (score 4):

There is also an alternate way to do that: `liftM2 cmp` will have type `IO [a] -> IO [a] -> IO Bool`, so `liftM2 cmp (readFile "dat1") (readFile "dat2")` is `IO Bool` and you can write

```
main = print =<< liftM2 cmp (readFile "dat1") (readFile "dat2")
```